# How to pass data from a SSR component to a CSR component in Nextjs

Tags: reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering

I recently moved to NextJS as I would like to have some of the benefits of SSR for SEO. But I am stuck at a feature that it was rather not complex in SPA React but not sure how to do this in NextJS. I have a parent component called MapPage which is SSR. Here there are server fetches the data from Django and passes it to two children. One called BusinessCards which is also SSR and the other is MapComponent which renders a map and therefore is CSR. What I want to accomplish is that on hover of any of the business cards the corresponding marker also hovers in the map.

Any ideas how to accomplish this? I think context could come up as a potential solution or even localStorage but the latter feels rather awful.